# Creating an Array of Linked list

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list

My program is meant to take a list of words and store each word under a letter reference in an array in ascending order. For example array of A-Z words apple, ape under a linked list under A referenced by 0, Zebra under Z referenced by 25. But when I use the standard first = new Node(word) I am not adding anything. I'm hopelessly lost.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
public class ArrayLinkedList 
{    
   /**
    The Node class is used to implement the 
    linked list.
   */

   private class Node
   {
      String value;
      Node next;

      /**
       * Constructor
       * @param val The element to store in the node
       * @param n The reference to the successor node
       */
      Node(String val, Node n)
      {
         value = val; 
         next = n;
      }
      Node(String val)
      {
          this(val, null);
      }
    }     

    private final int MAX = 26; // Number of nodes for letters
    private Node first;         // List head
    private Node last;          // Last element in the list
    private LinkedList[] alpha; // Linked list of letter references

    /**
    * Constructor to construct empty array list
    */

    public ArrayLinkedList()
    {
        first = null;
        last = null;
        alpha = new LinkedList[MAX];

        for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
        {
            alpha[i] = new LinkedList();
        }
    }

    /**
     * arrayIsEmpty method
     * To check if a specified element is empty
     */
    public boolean arrayIsEmpty(int index)
    {
        return (alpha[index].size() == 0);  
    }

    /**
     * The size method returns the length of the list
     * @return The number of elements in the list
     */
     public int size() 
     {
          int count = 0;
          Node p = first;
          while (p != null)
          {
              // There is an element at p
              count++;
              p = p.next;
          }
          return count;
     }    

    /**
     * add method
     * Adds the word to the first position in the linked list
     */
    public void add(String e)
    {
        String word = e.toLowerCase();  // Put String to lowercase
        char c = word.charAt(0);        // to get first letter of string
        int number = c - 'a';           // Index value of letter

        // Find position of word and add it to list
        if (arrayIsEmpty(number)) 
        {
            first = new Node(word);
            first = last;
        }
        else
        {
            first = sort(first, word, number);
        }     
    }

    /**
     * nodeSort method
     * To sort lists
     */
    private Node sort(Node node, String value, int number) {
        if (node == null) // End of list
        { 
            return getNode(value, number);
        }
        int comparison = node.value.compareTo(value);
        if (comparison >= 0)  // Or > 0 for stable sort.
        {
            Node newNode = getNode(value, number); // Insert in front.
            newNode.next = node;
            return newNode;
        }
        node.next = sort(node.next, value, number); // Insert in the rest.
        return node;
}

    private Node getNode(String value, int number) 
    {
        return first.next;
    }
    /**
     * get method
     * to get each word value from the linked list and return it
     * @return value
     */

    public LinkedList get(int index)
    {
        return alpha[index];
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        sBuilder.append("Word and occurrence in ascending order\n\n");

        Node p = first;

        while (p != null)
        {
            sBuilder.append(p.value + "\n");            
            p = p.next;
        }
        return sBuilder.toString();     
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it necessarily have to be an an array or can you use other collections as well?

Comment: You should try compiling this first... This wouldn't even compile.
`alpha[number] = new Node(word, first);` alpha[number] is a LinkedList, not a Node. That assignment is not possible. Compiler should tell you this. Also, you have one `first` and one `last` variable but you have 26 linked lists. In the add method you are treating the first and last variables as if they are attributes of only the linked list that is currently being edited (alpha[index]). This seems a bit fishy. If this is the case, you should probably have one `first` and one `last` for each linked list.

Comment: Your code has few design issues. One suggestion I have is, do not make the node class private, make it public and have a private list of Node's in `ArrayLinkedList` class.

Comment: I think you are simply mixing up two strategies... Either you use a java.util.LinkedList for each letter. Then, you do not need your own Node class (in a real word situation, this would probably be the preferable way). Or, you create your own Node class and handle the implementation of the list nodes yourself (if this is a school project in which you are expected to do so). Right now, it feels like you are doing something in between.

Comment: How would I have a first and last for each linked list?

Comment: This is what my assignment gives me:
For example, we can use an array of 26 elements to store each english word entered. Each element of the array will reference a linked list, where each list contains words starting with a specific letter in the alphabet. Each word that begins with the same letter is stored in a linked list whose head is referenced via the corresponding index value.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you are doing it this way. 
I can think of an easier way: use Map which will map a character (e.g. "A") to a LinkedList of Words.

Comment: Unfortunately my assignment outlines me to do use an array of linked lists to store english words in ascending order. but to reference letters a-z by number a=0, b=1, z=25.